# add some elements in tikz picuture - advanced tikz commands

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have implemented the following tikz picture:

[image]

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\tikzset{%
    neuron missing/.style={
        draw=none, 
        scale=2,
        text height=0.333cm,
        execute at begin node=\color{black}$\vdots$
    },
}

\newcommand{\DrawNeuronalNetwork}[2][]{
    \xdef\Xmax{0}
    \foreach \Layer/\X/\Col/\Miss/\Lab/\Count/\Content [count=\Y] in {#2}
    {\pgfmathsetmacro{\Xmax}{max(\X,\Xmax)}
        \xdef\Xmax{\Xmax}
        \xdef\Ymax{\Y}
    }
    \foreach \Layer/\X/\Col/\Miss/\Lab/\Count/\Content [count=\Y] in {#2}
    {\node[anchor=south] at ({2*\Y},{\Xmax/2+0.1}) {\Layer};
        \foreach \m in {1,...,\X}
        {
            \ifnum\m=\Miss
            \node [neuron missing] (neuron-\Y-\m) at ({2*\Y},{\X/2-\m}) {};
            \else
            \node [circle,fill=\Col!50,minimum size=0.3cm] (neuron-\Y-\m) at 
            ({2*\Y},{\X/2-\m}) {\Content};
            \ifnum\Y=1
            \else
            \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\LastY}{\Y-1}
            \foreach \Z in {1,...,\LastX}
            {
                \ifnum\Z=\LastMiss
                \else
                \draw[->] (neuron-\LastY-\Z) -- (neuron-\Y-\m);
                \fi
            }
            \fi
            \fi
            \ifnum\Y=1
            \ifnum\m=\X
            \draw [overlay] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- (state);
            \else
            \ifnum\m=\Miss
            \else
            \draw [overlay] (neuron-\Y-\m) -- (state);
            \fi
            \fi
            \else
            \fi     
        }
        \xdef\LastMiss{\Miss}
        \xdef\LastX{\X}
    }
}

\begin{document}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale = 0.3, x=1.5cm, y=1.5cm,
    >=stealth,font=\sffamily,nodes={align=center}]
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=T]
    \path  node[coordinate,minimum width=3em,minimum height=2em] (state) {State};
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=NN]
    \DrawNeuronalNetwork{/5/black/4///,
        /5/black/4//11/,
        /4/black/3//11/}
    \end{scope}

    \path (NN.south) node[below]{parameter $\theta$};
    \path(NN.east) -- node[above]{policy\\ $\pi(\theta,a)$}++ (2em,10em);
    \end{scope} 
    \node[fit=(T),label={[anchor=north west]north west:agent},inner sep=0.7em,draw]
    (TF){};
    \node[below=3em of TF,draw,inner sep=1.5em, fill=gray!30] (Env) {environment};
    \draw[<-] (TF.200) -- ++ (-8em,0) |- (Env.170) node[pos=0.27,right]{$r_t$};
    \draw[<-] (state) -- ++ (-16em,0) |- (Env.180) node[pos=0.31,left]{$s_t$};
    \draw[->] (TF.east) -- ++ (12em,0) |- (Env)
    node[pos = 0.3,right]{$a_t$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

I copied the code of the neural network (\DrawNeuralNetwork), so I have no real idea how it works (I am not really skilled at tikz). I just tried to fit is as best as possible how I want it. Now I want to add one element and I don't know how to. I want to add a rectangle behind the last neurons and connect each of the last neurons with an arrow to the rectangle as indicated in the sketch below. Then I want to connect the arrow to the added rectangle.

[image]

It would be nice if someone could help me.

Comment: Well you don't *need* to use complex commands, you can use normal commands and "copy paste" too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Neural network is drawn from scratch. Defined are new styles, used are `calc`, `chains` and `positioning`  libraries for positioning of neurons. Comments in code describe function of code parts:

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                calc, chains, 
                fit,
                positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2mm and 12mm,
  start chain = going below,
 annot/.style = {text width=3em, align=center},
   arr/.style = {-{Stealth[length=3pt,width=2pt]}, semithick},
  dots/.style = {text height=2ex, 
                node contents={$\vdots$},
                on chain},
   FIT/.style = {draw, inner sep=2mm, fit=#1, node contents={}},
   lbl/.style = {inner sep=2pt, font=\footnotesize}, 
neuron/.style = {circle, fill=#1!50,
                 minimum size=3mm, inner sep=0pt, node contents={},
                 on chain},
every edge/.style = {arr, draw, very thin, shorten > =0.5pt},
every label/.style = {align=center},
                        ]
% input layer nodes
\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
{
\ifnum\i=4
    \node (I-\i) [dots];
\else
    \node (I-\i) [neuron=green];
\fi
}
% middle layer nodes
    \node (H-1) [neuron=blue,
                 right=of I-1];
\foreach \i in {2,...,5}
{
\ifnum\i=4
    \node (H-\i) [dots];
\else
    \node (H-\i) [neuron=blue!50];
\fi
}
% out layer nodes
    \node (O-1) [neuron=red,
                 right=of {$(H-1)!0.5!(H-2)$}];
\foreach \i in {2,...,4}
{
\ifnum\i=3
    \node (O-\i) [dots];
\else
    \node (O-\i) [neuron=red];
\fi
}
%%%% conections
\coordinate[left=of I-3] (in);
    \foreach \i in {1,2,3,5}
\draw  (in) edge (I-\i);
%
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,5}
{
    \foreach \j in {1,2,3,5}
\draw   (I-\i) edge (H-\j);
}
\foreach \i in {1,2,3,5}
{
    \foreach \j in {1,2,4}
\draw   (H-\i) edge (O-\j);
}
%%%% out rectangle
\coordinate[right=of I-1 -| O-1.west] (out1);
\coordinate[right=of I-5 -| O-4.west] (out2);
\node (out) [FIT=(out1) (out2)];
    \foreach \i in {1,2,4}
\draw  (O-\i) edge (O-\i -| out.center);
%%%% neuron fit rectangle
\node (nrn) [FIT=(in) (I-1) (I-2) (out),
             label={[anchor=north west]north west:agent},
             label={[anchor=north east]north east: policy\\$\pi(\theta,a)$},
             inner ysep=4ex, yshift=3ex];
%%%% feedback
\node (env) [below=of nrn, 
             minimum height=5ex, text depth=0.5ex, 
             draw, fill=gray!30]    {environment};
\draw[arr]  (out.east)  -- ++ (2em,0)
                        |- (env) node[lbl, pos=0.25,right] {$a_t$};
\draw[arr]  (env.190)   -| ([xshift=-5em] in) node[lbl, pos=0.71,left]{$s_t$}
                        -- (in);
\draw[arr]  (env.170)   -| ([xshift=-3em] nrn.200) node[lbl, pos=0.75,right]{$r_t$}
                        -- (nrn.200);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is relly nice, thank you!